# Getting ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset from ListBox in PivotControl

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

I have a `PivotControl` that contains `ListBox` elements:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="SECTIONS" x:Name="pivotControl" ItemsSource="{Binding SectionViewModels}">
            <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <!-- -->
            </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!-- if you don't explicitly specify the height, the scrolling won't work -->
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StoryViewModels}" SelectionChanged="StoryList_SelectionChanged"
                                 Height="625" u:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.FetchMoreDataCommand}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <local:StoryControl />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot>
```

I want to get and set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` of a `ListBox` corresponding to a given `SectionViewModel` (which is the item source of the pivot control). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're some cases that you need to access view elements. For those cases using the VisualTreeHelper is the solution. You can find a [summary](http://miguelmadero.blogspot.com/2008/07/use-visualtreehelper-to-navigate.html) of it in my blog and some [helper extension methods](http://miguelmadero.blogspot.com/2008/07/use-visualtreehelper-to-navigate_18.html).

I recommend to use [SilverlightSpy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/) to see how the VisualTree is composed at runtime and be able to more efficiently navigate it.